# Why list comprehension of swapping cases work but a for loop does not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to swap cases of a `string` in Python 3:

The following code works:

```
print("".join([i.lower() if i.isupper() else i.upper() for i in s]))
```

But my loop does not:

```
s = 'Terra'
for i in s:
    if i.isupper():
        i.lower()
    else:
        i.upper()
print(s)
```

What is wrong with my loop? I know list comprehensions are just like condensed 1 liner loops and the code is pretty much the same here I guess. I know solutions like the `swapcase` function already exist, but I am training some logic here.

Comment: You are not assigning to a variable or not printing it. Please print it **print(i.upper(), end="")**

Comment: `i.lower()` and `i.upper()` don't change the string in-place - they return new strings, and your code with a `for` loop doesn't use those strings for anything.

Comment: right is not in place like `.sort()` just noticed that, thanks

Comment: Even if it was in an inplace method, `i` is a series of string objects that contain the same value as the corresponding value in `s` for that loop. Any change you make to `i` inside the loop will have no effect on `s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the list comprehension you're creating a list, but in the loop, you're not assigning `i.lower()` or `i.upper()` to anything.

To get the equivalent functionality with a loop you need to do something like:

```
s = 'Terra'
swap = []
for i in s:
    if i.isupper():
        swap.append(i.lower())
    else:
        swap.append(i.upper())
print("".join(swap))
```

In answer to your follow-up about which way is quicker I performed tests of all four methods discussed:

1. Appending to a list as above
2. Appending to a string with, e.g. `out_put_str += i.lower()`
3. Printing each letter on conversion with, e.g. `print(i.upper(), end="")`
4. Printing `s.swapcase()`

Option 3 was definitely the slowest, ~3 times slower than the others at 2ms, but the other methods were fairly similar and their time ranges overlapped, but they were all around 600 µs ± 200 µs

Comment: I was wondering which way is faster, by using `.append()` method like you did or increment like krishna did.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some comparative timings

Answer (score 2):

Try ths.

```
s = 'Terra'
out_put_str = ""
for i in s:
    if i.isupper():
        out_put_str += i.lower()
    else:
        out_put_str += i.upper()

print(out_put_str)
```